# ¿Es correcto escribir "min/mayúscula" o "men/mayores"?

Tags: gramática

Estaba hoy escribiendo a un amigo para darle unas credenciales informáticas, cuando quise decir que era importante poner las mayúsculas y minúsculas tal y como le decía - no es lo mismo en ese software escribir `FedorQui` que `fedorqui`.

Escribiéndolo, me pareció que escribir "mayúsculas y minúsculas" era muy largo (escribía con el móvil, con la consiguiente pereza / torpedad para escribir bien), así que puse:

> Escribe las **min/mayúsculas** tal y como te las paso

Luego me di cuenta que seguramente me había explicado bien, pero que había cometido una licencia estilística que seguramente la academia no acepta.

Así que me pregunto: ¿es correcto? Más generalmente: Si escribimos *hermanos/as*, ¿es acaso correcto hacer lo mismo al principio de las palabras comunes,separando con una barra la parte diferente y concatenando la común? A efectos prácticos, sería como escribir `(min/may)úsculas`, `(may/men)ores`, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La Real Academia de la lengua [dice lo siguiente](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=bYvzHZDvGD6fr29gvU):

> \1. Barra (/). La barra propiamente dicha consiste en una línea diagonal que se traza de arriba abajo y de derecha a izquierda. Se usa
>   en los casos siguientes:
>
> [...]
>
> b) Colocada entre dos palabras, o entre una palabra y un morfema,
>   indica la existencia de dos o más opciones posibles. En este caso
>   tampoco se escribe entre espacios y puede sustituirse por paréntesis
>   (→ paréntesis, 2c): El/los día/s pasado/s; Querido/a amigo/a.

De ahí deduzco que se podría usar con las palabras enteras minúsculas/mayúsculas pero no con la separación que se propone por no ser las palabras separables en morfemas del siguiente modo: min-úsculas y may-úsculas.

Comment: Interesante lo que comentas de los morfemas, puede que sea el motivo. Intento, sin embargo, buscar algún contraejemplo para ver si siempre es el caso.

Answer (score 1):

La pregunta es muy interesante desde varios puntos de vista.

En primer lugar, la verdad es que no recuerdo haber visto nunca en español poner *min/mayúsculas* o algo parecido, con el sentido de opción que da *hermanos/as* pero al principio de palabra. Sin embargo, si lo buscas en Google parece que a alguien se le había ocurrido ya. Yo habría puesto *min/mays* para aún más brevedad, y para aprovechar las abreviaturas correctas de los dos términos. No encuentro nada en la RAE al respecto, pero curiosamente también yo estoy ahora mismo usando un móvil, así que me resulta complicado acceder a todo el contenido de su web.

En segundo lugar, está la cuestión de la falta de una palabra como el *case* inglés para definir si la letra está en mayúscula o minúscula. He visto que un sinónimo de *letra mayúscula* es *letra capital*. Por tanto, y con el permiso de los economistas, se podría decir que una letra está capitalizada cuando está en mayúscula, y por tanto se podría hablar de capitalizar y capitalización. Conclusión: podrías decirle a tu amigo que respete la capitalización de las letras. Como bonus, *capitalizar* significa *convertir en capital*, lo que se puede aplicar a las letras capitales.

---

Preguntada a la RAE sobre el tema de *case sensitive*, me responden con el siguiente texto:

> *Case sensitive* podría traducirse por *sensible a* o *discrimina mayús./minús.*, si quiere abreviar los términos. A la inversa, *case insensitive* tendría como equivalencia *ignora mayús./minús.*
>
> La voz *caja* tiene una acepción relativa al ámbito de la impresión, y aparece en las expresiones *caja alta* y *caja baja*, que, respectivamente, hacen referencia a las mayúsculas y las minúsculas. No obstante, la traducción *sensible a caja* no resulta transparente y apenas se documenta.

No responde a la pregunta de si es correcta tu opción, pero da otra opción que también abrevia y está avalada por ellos. No me han dicho nada sobre la idea de *capitalización*, así que supongo que no valdrá.

La definición de *[caja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6dxYOPn)* mencionada por la RAE debe de ser esta:

> 23. f. *Impr.* Cajón con varias separaciones o cajetines, en cada uno de los cuales se ponen los caracteres que representan una misma letra
>       o signo tipográfico.

Comment: Qué pena que el castellano carezca de una traducción de _case sensitive_. Incluso la wikipedia titula su [artículo al respecto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Case_sensitive) con la versión inglesa. Eso sí, sugiere _sensible a mayúsculas_, que me gusta bastante.

Comment: Como copia Carlos en su respuesta, la RAE considera correcta la traducción directa, pero no la recomienda porque no se usa. El *case* de *case sensitive* no significa *caso* aquí, sino *caja*; simplemente, sucede que en inglés el uso de esa palabra se ha generalizado, mientras que en español se ha quedado solo en el ámbito profesional de la impresión.

Comment: Caramba, no había visto tu adición tras hablar con la RAE. Como la respuesta se ha salido un poco de mi pregunta inicial (más genérica, sobre si es posible utilizar partículas A/B para combinar dos palabras), propongo crear una pregunta aparte preguntando por _case sensitive_ y mover esta parte de tu respuesta allí (más lo que quieras añadir a ella).

Comment: @fedorqui Por mí sin problema...

Comment: Si es que tengo cierta manía por el orden :) [¡Hecho!](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17018/1674)

Comment: @fedorqui hecho por mi parte también. Sin embargo, hay comentarios de terceros en esta discusión sobre el añadido, por lo que no deberíamos eliminarlo de aquí para no dejar los comentarios carentes de sentido.

Comment: @Gorpik nótese que he añadido una pregunta específica sobre _case sensitive_. Carlos: de acuerdo, me parece bien.