# ¿"Case sensitive" en castellano?

Tags: traducción, solicitud-de-término, informática

A raíz de [una pregunta anterior](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16915/1674) surgió la duda de cuál sería la mejor manera de traducir **case sensitive** al castellano.

Esto es, ¿cómo podemos decir en castellano que el uso de minúsculas y mayúsculas importa, pues el soporte que las lee tiene en cuenta esta diferencia?

Este es un término muy usado en la zona de introducción de datos de entrada para el acceso a una web o aplicación (*log in*).

A mí se me ocurre decir algo más largo como **susceptible a may/minúsculas**, siendo este min/mayúsculas el origen de la pregunta anterior. *Susceptible* lo uso como una posible traducción de la palabra inglesa *sensible*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En un correo enviado a la RAE preguntando sobre el tema de *case sensitive*, me respondieron con el siguiente texto:

> *Case sensitive* podría traducirse por **sensible a** o **discrimina mayús./minús.**, si quiere abreviar los términos. A la inversa, *case insensitive* tendría como equivalencia **ignora mayús./minús.**
>
> La voz *caja* tiene una acepción relativa al ámbito de la impresión, y aparece en las expresiones *caja alta* y *caja baja*, que, respectivamente, hacen referencia a las mayúsculas y las minúsculas. No obstante, la traducción *sensible a caja* no resulta transparente y apenas se documenta.

La definición de *[caja](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6dxYOPn)* mencionada por la RAE debe de ser esta:

> 23. f. Impr. Cajón con varias separaciones o cajetines, en cada uno de los cuales se ponen los caracteres que representan una misma letra o
>       signo tipográfico.

Answer (score 7):

Una traducción adecuada podría ser:

> Distingue mayúsculas de minúsculas (is case sensitive)

o

> No distingue mayúsculas de minúsculas (is not case sensitive)

Answer (score 5):

Existen cuatro términos usados comunmente en el área de informática:

- "*Sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas*": Término formal y más común
- "*Sensible a mayúsculas*": Manera común de abreviar el término anterior.
- "*Sensible a la capitalización*": Término semejante al previo, que alude a las mayúsculas siendo "*letras capitales*" y a la "*capitalización*" como la acción de emplear mayúsculas en una oración (*Nótese que la RAE no tiene una entrada para esta acepción*).
- "*Distingue mayúsculas de minúsculas*": Alternativa usada para el primer término.

Aquí hay algunos ejemplos de cómo se usan los términos listados:

- [Microsoft Access no es sensible a mayúsculas y minúsculas](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSSH5A_7.1.1/com.ibm.rational.clearquest.admin.doc/topics/c_case_sensitivity.htm). (IBM)
- [Función CONTAR.SI sensible a mayúsculas.](https://exceltotal.com/funcion-contar-si-sensible-mayusculas/) (ExcelTotal)
- [Sensible](http://www.elbrujo.es/intranet/login.php) [a](https://www.andalucia.org/es/cuentas/entrar/) [la](http://wikileaks.jornada.com.mx/login_form) [capitalización](http://www.itl.cat/acl_users/credentials_cookie_auth/require_login?came_from=http%3A//www.itl.cat/forum/forum-de-sostenibilitat/forum_view%3Fset_language%3Des). (El Brujo, Andalucía, La Jornada, ITL)
- [¿Qué significa que distingue las mayúsculas y las minúsculas?](https://www.ups.com/content/mx/es/resources/sri/reg_faq1.html) (UPS)

**Nota adicional**

También se usa la variante que mencionas "*susceptible*", a continuación unos ejemplos:

- [Susceptible a mayúsculas](https://books.google.com/books?id=is2J44U4DpsC&pg=PA457&lpg=PA457&dq=susceptible%20a%20mayusculas&source=bl&ots=1-7h7ltets&sig=49LWuCUePaOzZEbZHBYoUzcQUy8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiVsf2ai67RAhUBTSYKHWaDC1oQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q=susceptible%20a%20mayusculas&f=false), publicado en "*Cómo programar en Java*" en el 2004
- [WebAbility es susceptible a mayúsculas y minúsculas](http://www.webability.info/?P=doc_wikiwa3&wiki=intermedio/clientes/alta) (...) (Documentación WebAbility)
- [(...) susceptible a mayúsculas y minúsculas.](http://prod005ws02.tecvirtual.mx:9010/PROD/bwskalog.p_disploginnew?in_id=&cpbl=&newid=) (Traducción para un sistema adaptado para [el Tecnológico de Monterrey](http://tecvirtual.mx/))

Cabe mencionar que de existir la variante "*susceptible a la capitalización*" no es muy común (No vas a encontrar resultados con la connotación correcta en la red), y la mayoría de los usos de "*susceptible a mayúsculas*" son copias del ejemplo en el libro mencionado anteriormente.

Answer (score 2):

Este PDF proveé información adicional sobre el concepto de las cajas en la impresión.

http://www.nebrija.es/~mramos/PB3187/teoria/Tipo.pdf (ver pág. 9)

Hace sentido este concepto aunque no este bien documentado. Sobre la impresión, estamos acostrumbrados a pensar en ella en su forma física tangible (un libro), pero tenemos la impresión digital, especialmente hoy día con los libros electrónicos/digitales.

**Sensible a la caja** o **discrimina la caja** parece ser una traducción aceptable.

Otro argumento a favor de esta traducción sería disminución en la cantidad de letras utilizadas comparado a la expresión: **Discrimina mayúscula/minúscula**. El uso esta frase es típicamente es un mensaje de asistencia en una pagina web (creación de una cuenta) y estos deben ser cortos e informativos.

Answer (score 0):

Siempre lo he traducido y lo he visto traducido como "Sensible al caso", si bien no estoy seguro de que sea *estrictamente correcto*, sí es, sin duda, la traducción más habitual.

Comment: Me suena rarísimo, la verdad. Parece una traducción literal, pero que solo se entiende si conoces el término inglés y lo relacionas. A mi padre le sonaría a chino :)

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo... pero siempre la he visto así

Comment: distingue I would rather prefer, but I think like you, it does not sound good to me, maybe people from South America can say that it sounds fine, but not to me