# ¿Cómo puede traducirse al español "camel case"?

Tags: traducción, vocabulario-técnico, solicitud-de-término, informática

¿Cómo puede traducirse al español "camel case"?

> CamelCase es un estilo de escritura que se aplica a frases o palabras compuestas.El nombre se debe a que las mayúsculas a lo largo de una palabra en CamelCase se asemejan a las jorobas de un camello. El nombre CamelCase **se podría traducir como Mayúsculas/Minúsculas Camello**.
>
> <sub>Fuente : [wikipedia: CamelCase](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)</sub>

A mí la verdad es que la propuesta de "Mayúsculas/Minúsculas Camello" no me gusta nada. Preferiría algo más como "**notación** camello" o algo mejor. Actualmente el término aceptado en la industria es el anglicismo. Un ejemplo de Wikipedia:

> Los hashtags no distinguen entre mayúsculas y minúsculas, pero a menudo se emplea el llamado *CamelCase* (o uso de mayúsculas en una posición distinta de la inicial) para mejorar la legibilidad.
>
> <sub>Fuente :  [wikipedia: Hashtag](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hashtag)</sub>

Dado que el uso de la escritura *camelcase* se esta haciendo popular debido a las nuevas tecnologias (más allá del ámbito de la programación, como se ve en en ejemplo de Twiter y los Hashtag), quizá sería interesante encontrar un término para este anglicismo.

Comment: Relacionado (no duplicado, pero interesante también para la discusión de los _cases_): [¿“Case sensitive” en castellano?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/17018/1674).

Comment: Siempre conocí ese tipo de escritura como [**"notación Pascal"**](https://techterms.com/definition/pascalcase)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Tipo camello** o **notación camello** creo que son las que menos duelen a la vista.

Hay otras notaciones camello que no se han comentado, pero que existen:

- *lowerCamelCase*. (tipo camello inferior) Notación camello cuando la primera letra está escrita en minúscula
- *UpperCamelCase*. (tipo camello superior) Notación camello cuando la primera letra está escrita en mayúscula.

Y si no estoy muy despistado, todo esto viene de la [*Hungarian notation* o notación húngara](http://www.tugurium.com/gti/termino.php?Tr=Hungarian%20notation).

> Convención linguística consistente en anteponer al nombre de la variable, función o estructura de datos, un prefijo que indica su tipo y ámbito de aplicación. La notación proviene de la tesis doctoral de Charles Simonyi, «Meta-Programming: A Software Production Method», que la desarrolló como una manera de evitar los errores que se producen en programación al manipular variables de tipos incompatibles. Con esta notación el nombre de la variables recuerda sus posibilidades de uso. La leyenda dice que el nombre proviene del extraño resultado de anteponer a las variables una serie de letras, la mayoría consonantes, y dado que el autor es húngaro y recordando la Notación Polaca, surgió el nombre de Notación Húngara.

Comment: Buena aportación lo de la notación húngara. Este post es además una contribución muy bien redactada y de gran calidad. En un par de días te has convertido en un profesional! Enhorabuena! Espero poder seguir viendo muchas de tus contribuciones en el futuro.

Comment: ¡Gran aportación, sin duda! Veo que citas un texto sobre la notación húngara, pero no lo encuentro en internet. Si está extraído de alguna web o libro o lo que sea, es bueno mencionar la referencia ([How to reference material written by others](/help/referencing)). Me sumo al comentario de @Diego, ¡gran trabajo en apenas unos días! Que sean muchas más.

Comment: Está en el Glosario de Terminología Informática, en la entrada [Hungarian notation](http://www.tugurium.com/gti/termino.php?Tr=Hungarian%20notation&Tp=T&Or=0), por supuesto.

Comment: La conocía como **notación Pascal** https://techterms.com/definition/pascalcase

Answer (score 6):

Durante discusiones de informática he escuchado tanto "*notación camello*", como menciona [fedorqui](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/users/1674/fedorqui) como "*[capitalización camello](https://defensor.info:3000/challenges/declare-javascript-variables)*".

Sin embargo, "*notación camello*" es más común, he aquí unos ejemplos:

- [La notación camello mencionada en Firebird en 2013](https://firebird21.wordpress.com/2013/10/03/la-notacion-camello/)
- [Reglas para el nombramiento de objetos, variables y clases, en 2010](http://www.javerosanonimos.com/2010/08/reglas-para-el-nombramiento-de-objetos.html)
- [Aprendiendo ASP .net en 21 lecciones avanzadas, libro publicado en el 2002](https://books.google.com/books?id=iXxI7pB8ntkC&pg=PA973&lpg=PA973&dq=%22notacion%20camello%22&source=bl&ots=oTtESQL6W3&sig=JniJ1tquGII9d5RuQtpFvey3ad8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDn7rylqrRAhUk9YMKHWZcBBcQ6AEIYjAM#v=onepage&q=%22notacion%20camello%22&f=false)

Answer (score 5):

Yo he inventado el término cameyúsculas para representar este tipo de escritura que aporta a la semántica de las variables en un programa.

Comment: Genial. Lamentablemente este post está perdido en el tiempo, por lo que dudo que te den puntos de aprobación, pero la invención es muy buena. Muchas gracias por compartir.

Comment: ESTO es castellano y merece ser *la* respuesta al post

Answer (score 4):

Creo que estamos ante uno de esos casos en los que la palabra inglesa ha arraigado tanto en el habla de los informáticos hispanohablantes que será muy complicado desterrarla.

A modo de ejemplo, en Stack Overflow en español encuentro 15 resultados de [*camelcase*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=camelcase) por ninguno de [*notación camello*](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=notaci%C3%B3n%20camello).

Sin embargo, encontré una interesante presentación llamada [Escribir en español en los nuevos medios](http://www.slideshare.net/margacabrera/escribir-en-internet-en-espaol) en SlideShare (ironías de la vida, un nombre en *camelcase*). En la diapositiva número 35 la autora menciona:

> Utilizamos (CamelCase) **SubiBaja**: #PresupuestosGenerales

Y la verdad es que me gusta el término: ¿intentamos potenciar su uso? Creo que es tan visual como *camel* y ocupa el mismo número de caracteres.

Comment: mmm.... tendría que ser SubiBajaCapitalización? jejejej..... Camel=subibaja, Case=???

Comment: +1, pero sigo prefiriendo `notación` porque así podemos decir: notación camello, notación Pascal, notación subibaja. Aunque "Subibaja" es como he oído llamar a veces a un balancín (posiblemente una corrupción de "Sube y baja"). La denominación de "caja" de la otra pregunta es interesante, pero si decimos "Caja camello; caja subibaja" no nos va a entender nadie.

Comment: @Diego entonces se podría optar por decir _notación SubiBaja_, para hacer más explícito su sentido. A mí tampoco me gusta nada lo de _caja_.

Answer (score 1):

Me gustaría más llamar a esta convención como '**estilo dromedario**'. Como ejemplo podría tomarse la siguiente oración:

> Es estilo utilizado para declarar las variables es el dromedario; mientras que el utilizado para las constantes es todo en mayúsculas.

Comment: La ventaja de "camello" sobre "dromedario" es que el dromedario tiene una sola joroba mientras que el camello tiene dos. Con una joroba tienes un patrón abajo-arriba-abajo, mientras que con el camello (dos jorobas) vuelves a subir. Dependería por supuesto de cómo de largo sea tu identificador. Si solo son dos palabras por supuesto solo vas a tener una mayúscula, pero lo suyo es que tengas más de una, y por eso creo que "camello" sería preferible a "dromedario".

Comment: @Diego sé que mi comentario es completamente irrelevante pero quería anotar que aunque popularmente se conocen como camellos y dromedarios, la verdad es que ambos son camellos. Uno es **camello bactriano** y el otro **camello dromedario**.   [referencia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camelus)